# Dynamically create temporary offline DataBase to save XML data from API on memory

Tags: java, xml, database, datatable

I want to create a temporary database on memory to read ans store XML data from the API.

I have been doing this in C# and .Net by simply creating a structured DataSet/DataTable and reading XML API data and store in it. Then use it for the other work and at the end dump it.

The XML data structure is already known, so I would create the datatable structure and then read XML and save rows one by one.

I would like to achieve the same flexibility in Java too. Still a newbie in Java desktop application development.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) with this connection URL: `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testDb`

This will ensure that your dataset is created in-memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use collection framework to store temporary data or you can use Sqlite for local database if you really need database.